# Why does my super class object instance affect my inherited class object instance?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, instance, superclass

I have a super class `Player`, which has `ArrayList<Card> cards`, and `ArrayList<Card> cardsOnTable`. I also have a class `Bot`, which extends the `Player` class. My `Card` class has the `used` boolean property. I have a method on `Player` class that returns the unused cards.

My problem is, when I set my cards used in one of my Bot object instances, `cards <ArrayList>` also changes in other instances. Why does this happen? Did I make a mistake about inheritance?

Here are my classes:

```
public class Bot extends Player{

    private int id;
    private String name; //added to print player at the end of war (I didn't know what to write) -Gonca
    private int warPoints; // war points
    private int boardNum; // for connecting with board city
    private int score;
    private Card lastCardPlayed;




    public Bot() {
        super();
        this.id = 0;
        this.name = "Bot " + (id + 1); //if not set, then it is a Bot and it has only number
        lastCardPlayed = new Card();
    }

    public Bot(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = "Bot " + (this.id + 1); //if not set, then it is a Bot and it has only number
        lastCardPlayed = new Card();
    }

    public Bot(int id, City city) {
        super(id,city);
        this.id = id;
        this.name = "Bot " + (id + 1); //if not set, then it is a Bot and it has only number
        lastCardPlayed = new Card();
        System.out.println("Bot constructor with City parameter");
    }
```

```
public class Player {

    private int id;
    private String name; //
    private int warPoints; // war points
    private ArrayList<Card> cards; // cards in hand
    private ArrayList<Card> cardsOnTable;
    private int boardNum; // for connecting with board city
    private int score;
    private City city;
    private ArrayList<Material> resources;
    int numberOfCoin;
    int numberOfClay;
    int numberOfOre;
    int numberOfStone;
    int numberOfWood;
    int numberOfLoom;
    int numberOfGlass;
    int numberOfPapyrus;
    int numberOfMilitary;
    int numberOfCivilian;
    int numberOfScienceRuler;
    int numberOfScienceStone;
    int numberOfScienceWheel;


    public Player() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.name = "Player " + (id + 1); 
        this.cards = new ArrayList<>();
        this.cardsOnTable = new ArrayList<>();;
        this.city = new City();
        this.resources = new ArrayList<>();
        this.score = 0;
        this.numberOfCoin = 3;
    }

    public Player(int id, City city) {
        this.id = id;
        this.city = city;
        this.name = "Player " + (id + 1); 
        this.cards = new ArrayList<>();
        this.cardsOnTable = new ArrayList<>();;
        this.resources = new ArrayList<>();
        this.score = 0;
        this.numberOfCoin = 3;
    }




    public ArrayList<Card> getCards() {
        ArrayList<Card> temp  = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++)
        {
            if( !(cards.get(i).isUsed()))
                temp.add(cards.get(i));
        }
        return temp;
    }





    public String addCardsToTable(Card c) {
        if(verifySufficientResources(c)){
            c.setUsed(true);
            cardsOnTable.add(c);
            return "";
        }else{
            return ("Resources not enough");
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGkYh.png)

```
public class Card {

    private String name; // name
    private ArrayList<Material> requirements; // materials for playing this card.
    private ArrayList<Material> earnings; // come from card materials
    private int Id; // special card id for implementing card chain
    private int nextCardId; // id of the free card from card chain.
    private String color; // card color
    private String photoName; // for photo directory
    private int ageNumber; // age number of card.
    private boolean orSituation;
    private String specialFunctionName;
    private boolean used;
    private int cardWarPoint; // bunu sonradan ekledim aşağıdakilere göre eklemek lazım- efe

    public Card(String name, ArrayList<Material> requirements, ArrayList<Material> earnings, int Id, int nextCardId, String color, String photoName, int ageNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.requirements = requirements;
        this.earnings = earnings;
        this.Id = Id;
        this.nextCardId = nextCardId;
        this.color = color;
        this.photoName = photoName;
        this.ageNumber = ageNumber;
        this.orSituation = false;
        this.specialFunctionName = "none";
        this.used = false;
    }

    public Card(String name, ArrayList<Material> requirements, ArrayList<Material> earnings, int Id, int nextCardId, String color, String photoName, int ageNumber, boolean orSituation) {
        this.name = name;
        this.requirements = requirements;
        this.earnings = earnings;
        this.Id = Id;
        this.nextCardId = nextCardId;
        this.color = color;
        this.photoName = photoName;
        this.ageNumber = ageNumber;
        this.orSituation = orSituation;
        this.specialFunctionName = "none";
        this.used = false;
    }

    public Card(String name, ArrayList<Material> requirements, ArrayList<Material> earnings, int Id, int nextCardId, String color, String photoName, int ageNumber, String specialFunctionName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.requirements = requirements;
        this.earnings = earnings;
        this.Id = Id;
        this.nextCardId = nextCardId;
        this.color = color;
        this.photoName = photoName;
        this.ageNumber = ageNumber;
        this.orSituation = false;
        this.specialFunctionName = specialFunctionName;
        this.used = false;
    }

    public Card(String name, ArrayList<Material> requirements, ArrayList<Material> earnings, int Id, int nextCardId, String color, String photoName, int ageNumber, boolean orSituation, String specialFunctionName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.requirements = requirements;
        this.earnings = earnings;
        this.Id = Id;
        this.nextCardId = nextCardId;
        this.color = color;
        this.photoName = photoName;
        this.ageNumber = ageNumber;
        this.orSituation = orSituation;
        this.specialFunctionName = specialFunctionName;
        this.used = false;
    }

    public Card(Card c){
        this.name = c.name;
        this.requirements = c.requirements;
        this.earnings = c.earnings;
        this.Id = c.Id;
        this.nextCardId = c.nextCardId;
        this.color = c.color;
        this.photoName = c.photoName;
        this.ageNumber = c.ageNumber;
        this.orSituation = c.orSituation;
        this.specialFunctionName = c.specialFunctionName;
        this.used = c.used;
    }

    public Card() {
        this.name = "";
        this.requirements = new ArrayList<Material>();
        this.earnings = new ArrayList<Material>();
        this.Id = -1;
        this.nextCardId = -1;
        this.color = "";
        this.photoName = "";
        this.ageNumber = -1;
        this.orSituation = false;
        this.specialFunctionName = "";
        this.used = false;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Material> getRequirements() {
        return requirements;
    }
    public void setRequirements(ArrayList<Material> requirements){
        this.requirements = requirements;
    }

    public ArrayList<Material> getEarnings() {
        return earnings;
    }

    public void setEarnings(ArrayList<Material> earnings) {
        this.earnings = earnings;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id){
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public int getNextCardId(){
        return nextCardId;
    }

    public void setNextCardId(int nextCardId){
        this.nextCardId = nextCardId;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getPhotoName() {
        return photoName;
    }

    public void setPhotoName(String photoName) {
        this.photoName = photoName;
    }

    public int getAgeNumber() {
        return ageNumber;
    }

    public void setAgeNumber(int ageNumber) {
        this.ageNumber = ageNumber;
    }

    public void setSpecialFunctionName(String specialFunctionName){
        this.specialFunctionName = specialFunctionName;
    }
    public String getSpecialFunctionName(){
        return this.specialFunctionName;
    }
    public boolean getOrSituation(){
        return this.orSituation;
    }
    public void setOrSituation(boolean orSituation){
        this.orSituation = orSituation;
    }

    public int getCardWarPoint() {
        return cardWarPoint;
    }


    public int getNumberOfRequiredWood(){
        for(int i = 0; i < requirements.size(); i++){
            if(requirements.get(i).getName() == "Wood"){
                return requirements.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfRequiredClay(){
        for(int i = 0; i < requirements.size(); i++){
            if(requirements.get(i).getName() == "Clay"){
                return requirements.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfRequiredOre(){
        for(int i = 0; i < requirements.size(); i++){
            if(requirements.get(i).getName() == "Ore"){
                return requirements.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfRequiredStone(){
        for(int i = 0; i < requirements.size(); i++){
            if(requirements.get(i).getName() == "Stone"){
                return requirements.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfRequiredGlass(){
        for(int i = 0; i < requirements.size(); i++){
            if(requirements.get(i).getName() == "Glass"){
                return requirements.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfRequiredLoom(){
        for(int i = 0; i < requirements.size(); i++){
            if(requirements.get(i).getName() == "Loom"){
                return requirements.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfRequiredPapyrus(){
        for(int i = 0; i < requirements.size(); i++){
            if(requirements.get(i).getName() == "Papyrus"){
                return requirements.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }



    public int getNumberOfEarningWood(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "Wood"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningStone(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "Stone"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningOre(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "Ore"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningClay(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "Clay"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningGlass(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "Glass"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningLoom(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "Loom"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningPapyrus(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "Papyrus"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningCivilian(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "Civilian"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningMilitary(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "Military"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningScienceRuler(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "ScienceRuler"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningScienceWheel(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "ScienceWheel"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int getNumberOfEarningScienceStone(){
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            if(earnings.get(i).getName() == "ScienceStone"){
                return earnings.get(i).getCount();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }


    public void setCardWarPoint(int cardWarPoint) {
        this.cardWarPoint = cardWarPoint;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("NAME: " + name + " ID:" + Id + " nextCardId: " + nextCardId + " color:" + color + " photoName: " + photoName + " ageNumber: "+ ageNumber + " orSituation: " + orSituation + " specialFunctionName: " + specialFunctionName);
        System.out.print("Requirements: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < requirements.size(); i++){
            requirements.get(i).print();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Earnings: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < earnings.size(); i++){
            earnings.get(i).print();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Card{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", requirements=" + requirements +
                ", earnings=" + earnings +
                ", Id=" + Id +
                ", nextCardId=" + nextCardId +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", photoName='" + photoName + '\'' +
                ", ageNumber=" + ageNumber +
                ", orSituation=" + orSituation +
                ", specialFunctionName='" + specialFunctionName + '\'' +
                ", cardWarPoint=" + cardWarPoint +
                '}';
    }

    public boolean isUsed() {
        return used;
    }

    public void setUsed(boolean used) {
        this.used = used;
    }
}
```

And here is the engine which deals with cards and players

```
public class PlayerEngine extends Application {

    private Player player;
    private ArrayList<Bot> bots;
    private ArrayList<Player> allPlayers;

    public PlayerEngine(int numberOfPlayers, City desiredCityOfHumanPlayer, ArrayList<City> citiesOfBots){
        allPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
        bots = new ArrayList<>();
        player = new Player(0, desiredCityOfHumanPlayer);
        allPlayers.add(player);
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers - 1; i++){
            Bot bot = new Bot(i, citiesOfBots.get(i));
            allPlayers.add(bot);
            bots.add(bot);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < bots.size(); i++){
            bots.get(i).print();
        }

    }
    public PlayerEngine(int numberOfPlayers){
        allPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
        bots = new ArrayList<>();
        player = new Player();

        allPlayers.add(player);
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers - 1; i++){
            Bot bot = new Bot(i);
            allPlayers.add(bot);
            bots.add(bot);
        }
    }

    public Player getHumanPlayer(){
        return player;
    }


    public ArrayList<Bot> getBots(){
        return bots;
    }


    public void matchPlayerWithCity(Player player, City city){
        player.setCity(city);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("inside start");
        CityManager cityManager = new CityManager();
        cityManager.createACities();
        cityManager.printACities();
        cityManager.createBCities();
        cityManager.printBCities();
        Player p = new Player();
    }

    public void distributeHands(ArrayList<Card> cards){
        System.out.println("number of players" + allPlayers.size());
        System.out.println("number of cards" + cards.size());
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            player.addToHandAtFirst(cards.get(count));
            count++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < bots.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
                bots.get(i).addToHandAtFirst(cards.get(count));
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] numberOfCardsOfAllPlayers(){
        int [] arr = new int[allPlayers.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = allPlayers.get(i).getCards().size();
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public int getHighScore(){
        int max=0;
        for(int i=0;i < allPlayers.size();i++){
            if( allPlayers.get(i).getScore()>max){
                max = allPlayers.get(i).getScore();
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
    public int getPlayerPoint(Player player) {

        return  player.getScore();
    }
    public void updatePlayerPoint(Player player,int point){

        player.setScore(player.getScore()+point);

    }
    public void increaseCoin(Player player,int coinNumber){

        player.setCoin(player.getCoin()+ coinNumber);

    }
    public void increaseWarPoints(Player player, int warPoints){

        player.setWarPoints(player.getWarPoints() + warPoints);

    }
    public Player getPlayer(int index){
        return allPlayers.get(index);
    }

    public ArrayList<Card> getCardsEntity(Player player){
        return player.getCards();

    }
    public void addToCardList(Player player,Card card)
    {
        player.addCardsToTable(card);
    }


    public void disjointCard(Player player,int cardNum){
        player.getCards().remove(player.getCards().get(cardNum));
    }


    public void startAttack(){
        // attack manager ile bağlanacak.

    }
    public void finishAttack(){
        // attack manager ile bağlanacak.

    }
    public void startXOX(Boolean bool){
        //xox game ile bağlanacak.

    }

    public ArrayList<Player> getAllPlayers(){
        return allPlayers;
    }

    public void printPlayers(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("LIST OF ALL PLAYERS");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("PLAYER");
        player.print();
        System.out.println("BOTS");
        for(int i = 0; i < bots.size(); i++){
            bots.get(i).print();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I suspect something in your *card* class is static. Could you include that code?

Comment: please check, if you are passing same Card Instance to both the bots.

Comment: You give the same cards to all bots and to the player. So if one modifies a card, this same card, referenced by the other bots, is modified for everyone. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: Who/where/which class is initializing/creating the cards?

Comment: actually I am distributing different card instances, which I got from ArrayList. CardEngine creates the cards then playerEngine distributes the cards. I genuinely do not understand how all of these share the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

in your `PlayerEngine.distributeHands(ArrayList<Card> cards)`

you are adding the same **instances** to players and bots
they handle the same **objects** passing through the same **references**
if a modification is made, it is made on the same objects and it will be visible by any other object which has the same reference